# API integrating third party apps to various Restaurant POS Systems

Tags: api, integration, point-of-sale, pos

I was wondering if anyone knows of or has used any API services that I could integrate my app with to push orders or get table information to/from Restaurant POS Systems.

I have googled around and the only solution that I have found is https://www.apideck.com/pos-api

However, they are still working on the types of solutions I need.

Any ideas other than directly integrating with different POS Systems separately would be appreciated.

I am trying to jump-start a business, however, I do understand that if it scales, would be better if I integrate with such services separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can talk to Chowly, the company that will offer you their API with documentation, to connect to POS Systems